# magento 2 store manager always returns default store id

Tags: magento-2.0

I'm implementing module which have to store different data for all stores, so i need get current store id and set id to db with new records. I'm trying get store id this way

`$storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();`

But when i change scope to another store (which has id "2") then $storeId still has value "1" (default store). I see that last param in my url has changed
`store/2/`
but in code has returned default store id. Any idea what causing that problem?

My sourcecode

```
<?php

namespace Sample\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tree;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;
use \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;


/**
 * Category container block
 */
class Supplier extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    /**
     * Category Map collection
     *
     * @var \Sample\Module\Model\Resource\CategoryMap\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_categoryMapCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Sample\Module\Model\Resource\CategoryMap\CollectionFactory $categoryMapCollectionFactory
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Sample\Module\Model\Resource\CategoryMap\CollectionFactory $categoryMapCollectionFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_categoryMapCollectionFactory = $categoryMapCollectionFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    /**
     * @param int $categoryId
     *
     * @return \Sample\Module\Model\Resource\CategoryMap\Collection
     */
    protected function getMapsForCategory($categoryId)
    {
        $categoryMapCollection = $this->_categoryMapCollectionFactory->create();

        $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();

        $categoryMapCollection
            ->addFilter('integrastore_category_id', $categoryId)
            ->addFilter('shop_id', $storeId)
            ->load();

        return $categoryMapCollection;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your source code.

Comment: Hi RiccardoT. I've added my sourcecode

Answer (score 1):

According to [this issue on git](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9741), storeManager isn't intended to return the current store.  Instead you can grab the parameter from the URL:

```
class CurrentStore 
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        //...
    ) {
       $websiteId = (int) $request->getParam('website', 0);
       // ... 
    }
}
```